# How to Pipe Typed Process to wai-conduit's responseSource?

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-warp, typed-process

I want to have warp run a process, then respond with that process' output. The output is assumed to be larger than the server's RAM; loading the entire output then responding is not an option. I'd thought that I could accomplish this using something like

```hs
withProcessWait_ (setStdout createSource "cat largefile") (pure . responseSource ok200 [] . getStdout)
```

but [`responseSource`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-17/wai-conduit-3.0.0.4/Network-Wai-Conduit.html#v:responseSource) uses `ConduitT i (Flush Builder) IO ()` and [`createSource`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.3.4/docs/Data-Conduit-Process-Typed.html#v:createSource) uses `ConduitT i ByteString m ()`. I could not figure how to convert a `ByteString` conduit to a `Flush Builder` conduit.

---

So I devised a solution that seems to work, but it's regrettably less simply defined:

```hs
responseProcess :: Status -> ResponseHeaders -> ProcessConfig in out err -> Response
responseProcess s hs cfg = responseStream s hs $ \send flush ->                                                                                                                                
     withProcessWait_ (setStdout createPipe cfg) $ \p@(getStdout -> h) ->
         let loop = do
             bs <- hGetSome h defaultChunkSize
             unless (BS.null bs) (send (byteString bs) *> flush *> loop)
         in loop *> hClose h
```

. Is this necessary, even if I may try prettying-it-up by wrapping in [`mkStreamSpec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/typed-process-0.2.6.0/docs/System-Process-Typed.html#v:mkStreamSpec) or something? Or is there a simpler method I'm missing?

---

**edit**: comments on the solution:

`intersperseC` lets me use `Chunk` and `Flush` together. That solves the `Flush Builder`/`ByteString` conversion problem. I haven't tested it, but it looks right and I trust it's been used.

However, I found that

```hs
withProcessWait_ (setStdout createSource "cat largefile") $ \p ->
    responseSource ok200 [] (getStdout p .| mapC (Chunk . byteString) .| intersperseC Flush)
```

closes the process handle too early. Thus I need to manage the pipe myself: using `createPipe` instead of `createSource`. But this means that I need to call `hClose` at the end, which means that I need a response handler that returns `IO ()`; the only one that does (excepting `responseRaw`) is `responseStream`, which uses `StreamingBody` as an *alternative* to Conduit. Thus I conclude that my original solution is needed and that Conduit cannot be used for streaming processes. Feel free to correct this if it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`responseSource` has type

> responseSource :: Status -> ResponseHeaders -> Source IO (Flush
>   Builder) -> Response

and the definition of [`Flush`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-17/conduit-1.3.1.1/Data-Conduit.html#t:Flush) is

> data Flush a = Chunk a | Flush

That is, a value of type `Flush Builder` is either a `Builder` or a command that instructs *warp* to flush the output stream.

[`Builder`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-17/binary-0.8.6.0/Data-Binary-Builder.html#t:Builder) is from the [binary](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-17/binary-0.8.6.0/Data-Binary-Builder.html#t:Builder) package. It's basically a representation of a chunk of bytes, optimized for efficient concatenation. And it can be constructed from a `ByteString`, using the [`fromByteString`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-17/binary-0.8.6.0/Data-Binary-Builder.html#v:fromByteString) function.

Knowing that, and using [`mapC`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-17/conduit-1.3.1.1/Conduit.html#v:mapC) from *conduit*, we can define this adapter:

```
adapter :: :: Monad m => ConduitT ByteString (Flush Builder) m ()
adapter = mapC (Chunk . fromByteString)
```

There's a problem though, the adapter never flushes. But we can intersperse flusing commands by means of [`intersperseC`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-17/conduit-1.3.1.1/Conduit.html#v:intersperseC):

```
adapter :: :: Monad m => ConduitT ByteString (Flush Builder) m ()
adapter = mapC (Chunk . fromByteString) .| intersperseC Flush
```

And what if we don't want to flush after every chunk? Perhaps we could use [`chunksOfCE`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-17/conduit-1.3.1.1/Conduit.html#v:chunksOfCE) to group the byte chunks before converting them into `Flush` values.